# jquery datatables pluginis is not work in asp.net web services

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am working on a project where i click on human image part and its show symptoms.For this i use web service which return json data perfectly.here is my web service code:

```
public class SympsService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetSymptoms(String organ_name)
    {
        List<symps> listSymptoms = new List<symps>();
        string CS=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EhealtsCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sendSymptoms", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = "@organ";
            parameter.Value = organ_name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter); con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                symps symp = new symps();
                symp.Sympt = rdr["SymptomsName"].ToString();
                listSymptoms.Add(symp);

            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listSymptoms));
        }
```

i use jquery datatables plugin for binding json data in a table.But when i click image my jquery code is not showing json data on the table.Here is my Jquery code:

```
if (e.key === 'toes'){
          $.ajax({
                url: "SympsService.asmx/GetSymptoms",
                data:{ organ_name: toes},
                method: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data){
                    var Variable = $('#symptomsTable').DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [ { 'data': 'Sympt' }]
                    });
                },
            error: function (error)
            {console.log(error);}
        });
    }
```

i also tried this jquery for showing json data in table but this is not working:

```
success: function (data) {
                    var symptomsTable = $('#symptomsTable tbody');
                    symptomsTable.empty();
                    $(data).each(function(index,symp) {
                        symptomsTable.append('<tr><td>' + symp.sympt + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                }
```

PLEASE,can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After your `success` element, can you make sure you are getting the right data by adding `console.log(data)` and letting us know what you get?

Comment: @jonmrich thank you..i just check this. It shows **Uncaught ReferenceError: toes is not defined** in this line : 'data:{ organ_name: toes}' 
can u plz tell me what does that mean?

Comment: @jonmrich thank u for ur advice... this was a mistake..when i use console.log(data) i find that. i need to use "toes" rather than toes.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `data:{ organ_name: "toes"}` instead of `data:{ organ_name: toes}`.
Always check your code carefully or you will going to be a fool like me.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the best way but this is how I usually hydrate my datatables from a web api call that returns json.

I usually make a function to hold my rows. something like

```
   function category(id, name, action) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.action = action;
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.categories = [];
}

var mymodel = new model();
```

then on my onsuccess of my ajax call I push the rows into the array.

```
success: function (data){
                  $.each(data, function( i, item ) {
                     mymodel.categories.push(new category(item.id, item.category, item.action));
  });
   var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    data: mymodel.categories,
    columns: [{
        data: 'id'
      }, {
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        data: 'action'
      }

    ],
    dom: '<"toolbar">frtip'

  });

                },
```

Comment: @brayan thank u for ud suggestion. i also try your way and it also works.